# path.join and electron.openExternal in win

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

```
const shell = require('electron').shell
shell.openExternal(path.join('base_path', 'child_path'))
```

If I join path like this in win,

the result of path.join('base_path', 'child_path') would be escaped and I can't open the link.

The separator(/) would be escaped.

I can open the link if I do like this.

```
shell.openExternal('base_path' + '/' + 'child_path')
```

But I think joining path like this could be dangerous.

Any way to solve this?

I want to use path.join().

Comment: What do you expect your final path to be relative to?  Current directory?  Module directory?  Root directory?  Full qualified path?  And, are `'base_path'` and `'child_path'` the real paths you're using?  I think we need to see the actual code here.  The actual path separator on Windows is `\\` so that may be why you are seeing some escaping when you look at the string.  I don't think you've shown us enough detail for us to know how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, the way I've solved this is to use the `toUnix` method of the [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) lib

```
upath.toUnix(upath.join(__dirname, "assets", "email.svg"));
```

> Normal path doesn't convert paths to a unified format (ie /) before
>   calculating paths (normalize, join), which can lead to numerous
>   problems. Also path joining, normalization etc on the two formats is
>   not consistent, depending on where it runs. Running path on Windows
>   yields different results than when it runs on Linux / Mac.
>
> In general, if you code your paths logic while developing on Unix/Mac
>   and it runs on Windows, you may run into problems when using path.
>
> Note that using Unix / on Windows works perfectly inside nodejs (and
>   other languages), so there's no reason to stick to the Windows legacy
>   at all.